# How can I view the IP addesses that have connected to a Azure Eventhub through Shared access policy?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

In Azure I have created a Eventhub Namespace with three Eventhubs. On each Eventhub I have created a Shared Access Policy. I have shared the Connection string-primary key to a third party vendor which connects to the Eventhubs.

In the Eventhub Namespace I have under Settings:Networking set

- `Public network access` = `All networks`

I want to use `Selected networks` instead of `All networks`, and then enter the IP adresses from the third party vendor.

To do this I first need to have a list of IP addresses that the third party vendor uses to connect to the Eventhubs.

How can I in Azure see the IP addresses that has connected to the Azure Eventhubs?

Comment: You can enable IP filters for you namespace and check denied client IPs from VNET diagnostics logs. Please check the page below for more details. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/troubleshooting-guide#what-client-ips-are-sending-events-to-or-receiving-events-from-my-namespace